How long should I wait before posting a second answer to a question I have already answered?
When I have just answered a question and a second approach strikes me a few minutes later, should I post it right away or wait for some time? Is it acceptable if I post it a few minutes later? I would like to know the official etiquette regarding this. This is the reference from which I was motivated to think so.

For those of us less familiar with math - why are there two possible answers? Are they different approaches?

Does it need to be a second answer? Why can't it be an edit on the existing answer? aka: "There are two solutions I can think of ..."

Because one Answer is one answer.. if somebody puts two different answers in one Answer, one good and one bad, how can anybody make a reasonable vote? There's a reason we can post multiple Answers, and should so so when it is appropriate.

@JourneymanGeek yes, they are 2 different methods.

This question to me seems one that should have been redirected to maths.meta as the advice given in response would depend on site culture. S/E's ideal of "one question - one best answer" is dominant, but absolutely doesn't apply to all sites, particularly the creative ones do easily fall outside that routinely. Perhaps mathematics does too, I know not - I'd want to ask on their meta.

If you would have posted an answer when it is your first Answer on a question, there is no reason not to post it as your second or subsequent Answer on the same question.
As long as it meets the requirements of an Answer post, writing a second answer as soon as you think of it, is totally fine.
Don't include a second answer in the same Answer post, because the voting on that post should be clearly applicable to the solution it provides. Including a second answer means other users cannot reasonably vote on them both as distinct responses (especially when one is good and one is bad), and users cannot determine which answer the score is based on.

This advice is highly site dependent. worldbuilding for example will offer multiple suggestions in a single post regularly.

Bad practice isn't good practice just because it's popular.
